# How to make domain extension in Django

Tags: python, django

I am making a website, and i want to add an extension for it, like users.example.com. I have searched a lot and came up with nothing. Would I have to create a whole new website, or is there something else that I could do?

Comment: If you point that sub domain at the same application then you could run it from the same project, but it's a complex subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a part of Django. You should define it in nginx configuration for your sub domain names and its routing.